# External Hard disk not showing in disk mangement but show in device manager

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, device-manager, disk-management

Yesterday when I was copying over over 130gb data from my internal hdd to external hdd using my laptop, the copying stopped at 20% says that the external hdd is not found. Then I tried unplugging it and plugging it again but it didn't show up on File explorer. The external hdd shows up in device manager and I could even safe eject it but still does not show up in disk management or file explorer.

Comment: Well that means the USB bridge fails to detect the drive. Either the bridge somehow died / got half-bricked, or the drive behind it died. If I were you I'd probably disassemble it get the drive out and connect it directly to a SATA port. (Note that some USB HDD has the USB board soldered on the drive. In any case, consider send it to the vendor for warranty repair first, if still possible.)

Comment: You can also consider downloading sg3_utils (1.46) and see if `sg_start --load` or so helps.

Comment: so is disassembling it the only way?